# .Net S3 Client hang while attempting to CopyObject

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Have an issue with asp.net s3 Object Copying using the asp.net s3 library.

I'm attempting to run the following code :-

```
CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest()
{
    SourceBucket = Bucket,
    SourceKey = s3FileKey,
    DestinationBucket = Bucket,
    DestinationKey = archiveS3FileKey                                
};

CopyObjectResponse copyObjectResponse = s3Client.CopyObject(copyObjectRequest);
```

The request will just hang on the `s3Client.CopyObject(copyObjectRequest);` line.

Using fiddler/wireshark i extract the http header seen below (proper bucket and auth keys removed)

```
PUT https://bucket-name.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/Archive/test.zip HTTP/1.1
x-amz-copy-source: /bucket-name/App/test.zip
x-amz-metadata-directive: COPY
User-Agent: MyDotNetConsoleApp
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.0
x-amz-date: Mon, 30 Jun 2014 05:34:53 GMT
Authorization: AWS <authorization code>
Host: bucket-name.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

When I alter the request by removing the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` the request runs fine. See below alteration to the s3 library from aws.
And the object will be copied to the new key

To get around this I added the following to the s3 Client library as a temporary measure, obviously though I would like to understand properly, if I'm not setting something in the client request.

```
(line 281 in AmazonWebClientService.cs)
if (state.WebRequest.Headers.Get("x-amz-copy-source") != null)
{
    state.WebRequest.SendChunked = false;
}
// this was the existing line above added. 
httpResponse = state.WebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I can delete object from the same s3Client object leading up to this copyobject, and also full permissions have been granted to this access key on this bucket.

Anyone have any idea what would cause this or how to get around it without altering the standard library supplied from aws ?